# Set UINavigationBar background image in ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am able to set the background for my navbar to a custom image in the app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method with this code:

```
UIImage *navBarImage;
navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I'm trying to add an option in my app to change the background image of the navbar when a switch is toggled, however it does not seem to work. Is it only possible to set the background image when the app launches? How can I do this after the app has already launched?

This is the code I have:

```
- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {
    UISwitch* switchView = sender;

        if (switchView.isOn) {
            UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"black_nav.png"];
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        }
        else {
            UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_nav.png"];
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:`  method:

```
[navbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"] 
               forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the default in each view doing this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width,
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
```

Comment: It made my navBar disappear in 8.3, but I removed the last line: sendSubviewToBack: and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

// Create resizable images

```
UIImage *gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"surf_gradient_textured_44"]
           resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
 UIImage *gradientImage32 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"surf_gradient_textured_32"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

// Set the background image for *all* UINavigationBars

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage32 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```